# mysql how to update transaction of where clouse with 100,000 different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

in my app I am allowing updating user data with  CSV file and the max limit is 100K rows .

each line in the csv file contains `c_id,a_id, country_code`

the user uploads a CSV file  then I am creating a query from that file

everything worked fine  until now

the problem is that my table grows and now contains 69,123,914 rows (last time I check)

and now the execution time takes almost 5 minutes

what is the best practice in this situation?

### This is the table structure

| Feild | Type | null | Key | Default | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c_id | bigint(20) | NO | PRI | null |  |
| a_id | int(11) | NO | PRI | null |  |
| country_code | varchar(2) | NO | PRI | null |  |
| last_update | timestamp | NO | "" | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| created_time | timestamp | NO | "" | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |  |
| is_deleted | tinyint(1) | NO | "" | 0 |  |

### This is the query generated from the CSV rows

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    is_deleted = 1
WHERE  is_deleted = 0
AND (
    (c_id = '1' AND country_code = 'TH' AND a_id = '-1')
    OR (c_id = '1' AND country_code = 'RO' AND a_id = '-1')
    OR (c_id = '1' AND country_code = 'PT' AND a_id = '-1')
    OR (c_id = '2' AND country_code = 'JM' AND a_id = '-1')
    OR (c_id = '35' AND country_code = 'AM' AND a_id = '-1')
    OR (c_id = '77' AND country_code = 'BA' AND a_id = '-1')
    OR (c_id = '77' AND country_code = 'MD' AND a_id = '-1')
    OR (c_id = '77' AND country_code = 'LT' AND a_id = '-1')
    OR (c_id = '123' AND country_code = 'TT' AND a_id = '-1')
    OR (..... until 100k) `
```

### This is the execution plan

| Operation | Params | rows | raw des |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INDEX_SCAN (range) | table: my_table; index: PRIMARY; | 100,000 | Using where |

Comment: I would load the CSV into a table and then join on that table rather than dynamically creating a huge WHERE clause.

Comment: the problem is with the db execution time, not the query building

Comment: If you do not want to use intermediate table then simply convert your dynamic query to `UPDATE my_table SET is_deleted = 1 WHERE is_deleted = 0 and (c_id, country_code, a_id) IN ((8338731, 'TH', -1), (8338731, 'RO', -1), ...)` at least. The presence of the index by `(c_id, country_code, a_id)` will improve.

Comment: OR (..... until 100k - does that mean every c_id = 8338731 ? And are only some of the 100k going to be updated?

Comment: PS. I think that removing `WHERE  is_deleted = 0` won't decrease the performance - MySQL updates the values which are changed really only, not all changed virtually.

Comment: no i mean there is a different 100k conditions

Comment: sorry i meant 100k

Comment: You didn't explain what the data in the table represents, nor what the update query is supposed to do. That makes it difficult for us to suggest an alternative (better) approach. As I read it the only thing the query does is set the `is_deleted` flag to 1 for something. I also find it weird that you say, the query is fine, the problem is with the execution time. Those two are often closely related.

Comment: it seems like you completely understand the problem  you need to set is_deleted to 1 where all these condition are true @KIKOSoftware

Comment: 'where all these condition are true ' - you mean where ANY OF  these condition are true otherwise you wouldn't be using or.

Comment: Why can't your app do this since it only has 100k rows to deal with?

Comment: the updates takes more then 5 minutes I have more then 70 mil rows

Comment: But you are only updating 100k right?

Comment: yes i am only updatin 1 00k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the comment above from @Bee_Riii, you should create a new table with the following fields:

```
c_id    | country_code | a_id
8338731 | TH           | -1
8338731 | RO           | -1
...
```

Then, rephrase your update query to add logic to assert that a given record is present in this lookup table:

```sql
UPDATE my_table t1
SET is_deleted = 1
WHERE
    is_deleted = 0 AND
    (c_id, country_code, a_id) IN (SELECT c_id, country_code, a_id
                                   FROM lookupTable);
```

The performance of the lookup can be optimized by adding an appropriate index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON lookupTable (c_id, country_code, a_id);
```

Comment: Multiple-table UPDATE syntax is more obvious in this case. `UPDATE my_table t1 JOIN lookupTable t2 USING (c_id, country_code, a_id) SET t1.is_deleted = 1 WHERE t1.is_deleted = 0`.

Comment: @Akina You're right, I could have also used an update join.  I guess my intention was to keep the query as close to the original as possible.